# Event to create a Page when a user creates one Page in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

I am working on triggering an event to create a page automatically, when user creates a page.

```
namespace TestEventHandler
{
    [TcmExtension("MyEventHandlerExtension")]
    public class MyEventHandler : TcmExtension
    {
        public MyEventHandler()
        {
            Subscribe();
        }

        public void Subscribe()
        {
            EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, SaveEventArgs>(HandlerForProcessed, EventPhases.Processed);
            //EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, PublishEventArgs>(HandlerForInitiated, EventPhases.Initiated);
        }

        private void HandlerForProcessed(Page subject, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
        {
            //create page.
            Tridion.ContentManager.Session mySession = new Tridion.ContentManager.Session(@"user");

            XmlElement XmlElement = null;
            Page newPage = new Page(XmlElement, mySession);

            newPage.Title = subject.Title + "_auto";
            newPage.FileName = subject.FileName + "_auto";
            newPage.PageTemplate = subject.PageTemplate;

            newPage.Save(true);
            newPage.CheckOut();

        }
    }
}
```

It's not creating the page automatically. I think some modification is required for this code.

I am getting error "Impersonation by this user requires the Machinename\MTSUser account to be configured as impersonation user".

Can anyone help with the modifications needed? I am using the TOM.net API for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is due to the new Session you are trying to create. That should not be necessary. You can get it from Page `subject.Session`.

Additionally, you are using the wrong constructor for the Page. Check out the documentation.

Sample code:

```
Page page = page = new Page(session, new TcmUri(sg));
page.Title = theTitle;
page.FileName = new Regex("\\W").Replace(theTitle, "");
page.PageTemplate = session.GetObject(pt) as PageTemplate;
ComponentTemplate componentTemplate = session.GetObject(ct) as ComponentTemplate;
page.ComponentPresentations.Add(
        new ComponentPresentation(component, componentTemplate));
page.Save(true);
```

The parameters you need are `sg`, `theTitle`, `pt`, `ct`, `component`. You could read them from Folder metadata for example.